# Parse my business_log using grok filter (Logstash)

Tags: logging, conditional-statements, logstash, logstash-grok

Some rows of my `business_log`:

```
2016-11-28 00:00:00.7000 INFO : OneTwoThreeHandler.GetBot 
    Cannot find a bot: Rak 20000
2016-11-28 00:00:00.7000 INFO : OneTwoThreeHandler.GetBotPlayer 
    Cannot find a bot: COIN 50000
2016-11-28 00:00:01.4812 INFO : OneTwoThreeHandler.GetBotPlayer 
    Find a bot: 1219552640:ut:coinu - rak: 6703098 - coin: 2721975
2016-11-28 00:00:01.4812 INFO : OttMatchSolo.Matched
    Solo Matched: 1:Rak
```

I want to parse this log based on "keyword" such as `OneTwoThreeHandler.GetBot`, `OneTwoThreeHandler.GetBotPlayer`, `OneTwoThreeHandler.GetBotPlayer`, or `OttMatchSolo.Matched`.

Because with each "keyword", the rest of row log is different. I think that I can use grok conditionals, can anyone show me how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with, supposing that the `message` field contains your log :

```
if [message] =~ /OneTwoThreeHandler\.GetBotPlayer/ {
    ...
} else if [message] =~ / OneTwoThreeHandler\.GetBot/ {
    ...
} else if [message] =~ /OttMatchSolo\.Matched/ {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

With each branch containing the specific configuration for those specific logs.

See this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) for more information on conditionals in logstash configurations.

You'll need to put your logs through a multiline filter/codec or do the operation with your shipper so that your log are on a single line, like this:

```
2016-11-28 00:00:01.4812 INFO : OttMatchSolo.Matched Solo Matched: 1:Rak
```

---

Or you can put more than one grok pattern in one grok filter:

```
grok{
    match => {
        "message" => [
            "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{LOGLEVEL} : OneTwoThreeHandler.GetBotPlayer %{GREEDYDATA}",
            "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{LOGLEVEL} : OneTwoThreeHandler.GetBot %{GREEDYDATA}",
            "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{LOGLEVEL} : OttMatchSolo.Matched %{GREEDYDATA}"                
        ]
    }
}
```

You'll still need to perform the multiline joining for it to work.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I solved problem but i am meeting troubles in reparse a log. I added start_position => "beginning",  sincedb_path => "NUL". But it still doesn't work

Comment: @hph2015 `sincedb_path => "NUL"` is for windows. If you're on linux, use "/dev/null". If you're on windows or it still does not work, set the sincedb_path to somewhere else, so that Logstash creates another sincedb file and reparse the log.